# Вопрос по запуску приложения

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Я новичок в программировании для Андроида. Решил писать приложение в Xamarin на С#. 
Вопрос такого плана, у меня готов axml файл, где отрисован сам дизайн. В MainActivity прописано это:

```
ImageButton logoButton = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.logoButton);
        ImageButton cartButton = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.cartButton);
        ImageButton privateButton = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.privateButton);
        ImageButton homeButton = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.homeButton);
        ImageButton nextButton = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.nextButton);
        ImageButton previousButton = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.previousButton);
```

Насколько я понял - это подключение кнопок, чтобы их видел программа при запуске?

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятен вопрос, но ответ нет - это не подключение кнопок, это сами кнопки. На них можно вешать события, изменять их названия и прочие параметры.
Что-то типа:

```
Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnName);

button.Text = string.Format ("{0} clicks!!", count);
button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format ("{0} clicks!!", ++count); };
```

Раз возникают подобные вопросы, вам лучше посмотреть/запустить примеры, они все лежат вот тут:

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples

К примеру обычное создание кнопки

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/Button